# How to convert String to Date in java whatever system format is

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to convert a date string to date object in java regardless of current system date format. Because I want to get my custom date format to store in database. The following is my code and please advice me the way.

```
public static String dateToString(String date){
    if(date.equals("")) return "";
    if(date == null || date.length() == 0){
        return "";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        Date l_date =  format.parse(date);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(l_date);
        String year = String.format("%04d", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String month = String.format("%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        String day = String.format("%02d", calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        return year + month + day;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

For SimpleDateFormat, it can only parse the format I heard coded.

```
dateToString("16/04/2015");
```

It can convert for above code. But, when I try with the following format

```
dateToString("Thursday, April 16, 2015");
```

I go Unparseable date: "Thursday, April 16, 2015" error.

Comment: Use `return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(calendar.getTime());` as month in calendar is counted from 0.

Comment: Do not rely upon strings for communicating with your database. For date-time values, use date-time objects. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, use the java.time classes with `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to convert a String in `EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy` format with the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`...

Start by using the correct format for the `String` you trying to convert, the use what ever format you want to convert it back...

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String value = to.format(from.parse(dateString));
```

Now you could use something like [`DateUtils.parseDate(String, String[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) which allows to supply a number of different formats, but is still limited to what you might know.

A better solution would be to store the `Date` value directly within the database.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer. But, I don't want to store Date value directly in the database because client computer may have different date format and I just want to convert them back to my custom format before inserting to database.

Comment: That's exactly my point though, store the `Date` in the database, then you don't have to care about the format (and you shouldn't), you should, where ever possible provide formatting of the objects in a format which the user is expecting, not what you want

Answer (score 0):

- You are passing wrong parameter to SimpleDateFormater
- Use
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy") instead of SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
- It resolve your Unparseable date issue.

Comment: Thank you @Ranjeet. But, I mean is I just want to convert any date format to my custom format. Is there any way to convert variable date format to a specific format?

Comment: @Thiha Zaw : Then you need to write regex for all possible combination.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
public static String dateToString(String date){
    if(date.equals("")) return "";
    if(date == null || date.length() == 0){
        return "";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat formatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat formatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");

    try {
        Date l_date =  formatIn.parse(date);
        String result = formatOut.format(l_date);
        return result;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

but if you want to put some data into database you may also use instead String java.sql.Date

something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();

Connection conn = ...
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("...");

long lDate = format.parse(sDate).getTime();
java.sql.Date dDate = new java.sql.Date(lDate);
ps.setDate(1, dDate);
```